# How do I make a GUI that behaves like this?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, dynamic, window, constraints

This is difficult to explain without illustration, so - behold, an illustration, cobbled together from screenshots of a few hello-world examples and a lot of Paint work:

[image: GUI mockup]

I have started out using Windows Forms on .NET (via IronPython, but that shouldn't be important), and haven't been able to figure out very much. GUI libraries in general are very intimidating, simply because every class has so many possible attributes. Documentation is good at explaining what everything does, but not so good at helping you figure out what you need.

I will be assembling the GUI dynamically, but I'm not expecting that to be the hard part. The sticking points for me right now are:

- How do I get text labels to size themselves automatically to the width of the contained text (so that the text doesn't clip, and I also don't reserve unnecessary space for them when resizing the window)?
- How do I make the vertical scrollbar always appear? Setting the VScroll property (why is this protected when AutoScroll is public, BTW?) doesn't seem to do anything.
- How come the horizontal scrollbar is not added by AutoScroll when contents are laid out vertically (via `Dock = DockStyle.Top`)? I can use a minimum size for panels to prevent the label and corresponding control from overlapping when the window is shrunk horizontally, but then the scrollbar doesn't appear and the control is inaccessible.
- How can I put limits on window resizing (e.g. set a minimum width) without disabling it completely? (Just set minimum/maximum sizes for the Form?) Related to that, is there any way to set minimum/maximum widths or heights without setting a minimum/maximum size (i.e. can I constrain the size in only one dimension)?
- Is there a built-in control suitable for hex editing or am I going to have to build something myself?

... And should I be using something else (perhaps something more capable?) I've heard WPF mentioned, but I understand that this involves XML and I really want to build a GUI from XML - I already have data in an object graph, and doing some kind of weird XML pseudo-serialization (in Python, no less!) in order to create a GUI seems incredibly roundabout.

Comment: You don't have to use XAML when doing WPF, it just makes things easier. Petzold's WPF book doesn't even go near XAML until the second half, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using WPF.

Getting access to the functionality from IronPython is more involved than I would have expected:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceByName("PresentationFramework, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")
clr.AddReferenceByName("PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")
clr.AddReferenceByName("WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")
import System.Windows
```

(I'm not sure if I can/should change the version number. The `PublicKeyToken` presumably has to do with some kind of DLL signing for security purposes; I don't know why WPF requires this but WinForms didn't.)

Since the namespaces for widgets get quite hairy and there are a lot of names that I want to import, I set up some dynamic import code:

```
def Import(namespace, what):
    if isinstance(what, str):
        globals()[what] = getattr(namespace, what)
    else:
        for k, v in what.items():
            if k: namespace = getattr(namespace, k)
            for name in v:
                Import(namespace, name)
```

After figuring out the right combination of layout tools (which wasn't as easy as this summary makes it sound), everything seems to "just work" and I'm quite pleased. The scroll behaviour is accomplished by setting up a `ScrollViewer` inside the main window and setting the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Auto`. Inside the `ScrollViewer` I put a `StackPanel` which stacks the "field frames", each of which is a `Grid` with two columns (I add two default `ColumnDefinition` s to the `Grid.ColumnDefinitions`). I set the "label" up in column 0, and the "value" widget (combo box, button, whatever) in column 1, with a `HorizontalAlignment` of `Right`.

I haven't set up the nested panels yet, but it seems like it shouldn't be difficult. I've already played around with the system for hooking up events to buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use Java/Swing that basic form should be pretty easy.  I'd like to say that the Netbeans IDE has a pretty good WYSIWYG GUI editor.  Even though it is pretty good I'd by lying if I said that is all there is to it.  You have to understand Swing to get things the way you want or you'll be bashing your head against the wall. It's free.  Most of what you ask for are properties of the GUI builder, you'll need to at least look before asking specifics.

I've had very little experience with Visual Basic, something about the language aggravated me but there is nothing I've seen easier to slap a simple GUI together with.

Comment: I'd like to stick with the .NET platform if possible, but my question is really language-agnostic - I want to find a **library** that can do this, and find out how to make it do the things described.

Comment: Swing is more than capable of these things. Another option is a web front end. Again it is probably even easier to get a form that looks more less like what you've demonstrated. As long as this is an intranet application this would make sense.  Then jQuery would be a great library.

Comment: Java GUIs are much reviled. OP is clear that if prefers .net. I'm not sure IronPython, great though it is, is the ideal choice for GUI work. This should be trivial to do in C# and WinForms with the Visual Studio form designer.

Comment: Personally, I think WPF would be a good choice here, and it actually has IronPython support in Visual Studio...

Comment: I'm using IronPython because it's fundamentally a Python program to start with - it's my favourite language, and dynamic typing is really coming in handy so far. I wanted to use the .NET platform for interop reasons - I have a plugin system, and also I might want to optimize some of the internals at some point, and don't want to have a compiled C module. I don't really see why the implementation language matters very much when using something like WinForms or WPF.

Comment: My primary OS is Ubuntu ;) This technology (WinForms WPF) is not cross platform (Mac uses mono as well so they are in the same camp).  At least the implementations are not currently on equal footing to the point of causing serious issues. Java should run the same everywhere unless the programmer went out of the way to make it otherwise.  If you like Python there is Jython.  There is no reason why you would need a compiled C module if you did so.  Anyways try out the Netbeans GUI builder you can probably have a GUI that looks the way you want in short order.

Comment: Never mind, I just want to point out that .net is not language agnostic (a set of languages yes, but not _any_ language on _any_ platform equally). So to claim language does not matter is false.